# Same size of plus and minus signs in title using gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I'm trying to plot a couple of different graphs in `gnuplot`, using the `epslatex` terminal. 
The legend for each graph is constructed on the form `title "A=-1.2345+6.7890i"` (essentially a complex number), but with different numbers.

Now for my problem: *The plus and minus signs in different titles have different horizontal length*.

I'd like the labels to have aligned real and imaginary parts, but if the length of the plus/minus signs are different, this is not the case.

So, my question is, is there any way to set the plus and minus signs in the legend to have the same horizontal length?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In math mode the plus and minus sign have the same length:

```
set terminal epslatex standalone header '\newcommand{\im}{\textrm{i}}'
set output 'foobar.tex'
plot x title "$A=-5.5545+6.7890\\im$", x**2 title "$B=+1.2345+6.7890\\im$"
set output
system('latex foobar.tex && dvips foobar.dvi && ps2pdf foobar.ps')
```

[image]